# Angular2 - How to bind radio buttons to boolean object properties

Tags: angular

I have a pretty simple model that looks like this:

```
export class Answer {

  constructor(public text: string, public isCorrect: boolean = false) {
  }

}
```

and I want to bind it to a radio button in such a way that if the radio button is selected, the `isCorrect` property is `true`, otherwise it is `false`. What is the proper way to go about this?

To be clear, I would have an array of `Answer`s, and each `Answer` would have a single radio button.

[Plnkr Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/euuOC2Ir6qMViSvcbsYA?p=preview)

My template so far looks like this:

```
<label *ngFor="let answer of answers">
  <input #rad type="radio" name="answer-{{questionIndex}}" [(ngModel)]="answer.isCorrect" [value]="rad.checked">
  {{answer.text}}
</label>
```

Comment: Please add the code that demonstrates what you have tried.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Template added!

Comment: You talk about an array but I can't see an array in the code in your question.

Comment: I think you should provide a Plunker that demonstrates what you tried, what the current behavior is and what the expected behavior is.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - I've created a plunker here - https://plnkr.co/edit/uWr2bU0L3RdWLKzylwkH?p=preview

For some reason, only the last radio button gets checked, regardless of which radio button you click on. Additionally, selecting a radio button sets the value to true, but if you select a different option, the previously true option is still set to true.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - I got a plunker working with the desired behavior. I'm not happy with the implementation though. Curious to know if there's a better way to achieve this. https://plnkr.co/edit/euuOC2Ir6qMViSvcbsYA?p=preview

Comment: I don't know a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue.  It's kind of a design problem.  Radio buttons are designed to allow a user to select a single value from a list, so binding them each to a separate boolean isn't consistent with what they're meant to do.

Like you, I wanted to use radio buttons because of their 'single value' character without doing a bunch of extra javascript work to force their behavior on my data structure when the form is submitted.  Ultimately, I worked around this using the (change) event binding to update my data structure accordingly whenever a radio button is clicked.

Template:

```
<input *ngFor='let answer of answers; let a = index' type='radio' name='question.id' 
  (change)='handleRadio(a)>
```

Component:

```
handleRadio(answerIndex: number): void {
  this.answers.forEach((answer) => {
    answer.checked = false;
  });
  this.answers[answerIndex].checked = true;
}
```

Note that this will break if you try to reload the form from your component data - in that case, I needed to change my internal data structure to reflect the radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to run your plunker example. But figuring out the solution to your question. Here is the working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b834qr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**Template Code**

```
<!-- For checkboxes buttons -->

<div  *ngFor="let button of buttons">
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="button.checked">
{{button.value}} {{button.checked}}
</div>

<!-- For Radio buttons-->
<div  *ngFor="let button of buttons1.options">
<input type="radio" [value]="button.text"
               name="sex" [(ngModel)]="buttons1.value" >

</div>
{{buttons1.value}}
```

**TS Code**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  temmp= false;
  name = 'Angular';
  buttons =[{
    value: "red"
  },
  {
  value:"green",
}]

 buttons1 ={
   options : [
    new Answer("Red"),
    new Answer("Blue"),
    new Answer("Green"),
    new Answer("Orange")],
value:""
 }

}


class Answer {

  constructor(public text: string, public isCorrect: boolean = false) {
  }

}
```

if you have any question. let me know.

**Side Note:** Please use **stackblitz** instead of plunker.